# NodeJS extract array buffer for video as images

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video, canvas

What i want to do is grab a video. And extract the frames from it as images. This is all being done in node so i don't have a video tag.

I am using openvg-canvas with this. any ideas on how to achieve this?

The problem is that openvg-canvas can print directly to the screen over the console. so i can print images and draw and use all the canvas api. The only thing i don't have access to is the video tag but cause canvas can't make videos, it can only use the imageData from each frame.

Any idea how i can get the imageData from a video but get the imageData from each frame. Alot of the packages i see only allow me to download and save the image but to save the image to disk and read it again would be a huge performance lost.

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to get the base 64 image of the video

Answer (score 0):

There is [luuvish/node-ffmpeg](https://github.com/luuvish/node-ffmpeg) package. It is C++ binding for ffmpeg (instead of cli wrapper). It provides low level API. So I assume you'll able to read data directly from memory with it's API and then convert it into base64.